# Is there any way to change the default validity period of a refresh token in windows azure ACS

Tags: windows, azure, acs

Is there a way to change the validity period of a refresh token within Windows Azure Access Control Service. Based on the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142382%28v=office.15%29.aspx), refresh tokens last a year but I cannot find a way to change that, either on the portal or via the management service. I am aware of the token time out when crating a relying party application but this, as I understand it, refers to the time out of the access token not the refresh token.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,

User1426145

Answer (score 1):

With OAuth 2.0, the refresh token has expiration time sent along with it and as you described in case of above the limit is about ONE year. You can not change the refresh token validity period once it is issued so you have two option to maintain it alive. Trying to keep track of its validity or when you hit INVALID_TOKEN error, you can  to call the same refresh token service to receive a brand new refresh token again.